# WebRTC and socket.io WebSockets heartbeat

Tags: tcp, heartbeat, websocket, distributed, sctp

I create an application using WebRTC data channels (ordered, reliable) and socket.io WebSockets as signalling server.

Assumptions (please confirm / neglect them)

- WebRTC SCTP & socket.io send heartbeats, but their interval may be different
- if a crash is detected using heartbeats, the connections (DataChannel and WebSockets) will be CLOSED and can NOT be reused if the peer was just temporarily disconnected
  --> the temporarily crashed peer MUST reconnect

Is it possible to configure the WebRTC heartbeat interval / timeout or is there any default value used in Chrome and Firefox, that I can rely on?

(related to this question:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/255057/p2p-locking-using-webrtc-and-socket-io-for-streaming-incremental-game-state
)